# Find total for 2 columns then find the average in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to  get a formula in excel for the total for 2 columns. The formula is needed for column B and then column A. I need to add the totals for column B and then column A. Once I have these I need to divide the answer for Column B with the answer to column A.  Both columns have about 10 to 15 rows of data.

For example column B is (3+4+7), column A is (8+10+5) then divide the answers for the totals of column B and A (in this case) 23/14.

If the cells had 0 in both (column B and A) I want the result to show 0 not the running total. How would this be done?

Please could someone advise how to do this in one formula.

Deepi

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "The average of these figures" Perhaps something like: `=Sum(B1:B10)/Sum(A1:A10)`?

Comment: Hi Deepi, welcome to SO. Have you tried to solve this problem yourself? Take a look at the `SUM` function in excel and the `/` operator. It's quite easy. give it a try and if you're still stuck , you can edit this question and add to it what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: I think I might have missed the SUM against the other column therefore it wasn't working. I will try that.